# PHP: why page doesn't get updated when using redirect

Tags: php, redirect

I have a code that edits a content in a page and redirect me to that page. It successfully redirects me to that page but it doesn't update the content. i have to press <kbd>F5</kbd> so that the page will refresh and gets updated.

This is the redirect i'm using

```
 if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql_pcr)){
    header("location:http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/cert/forms/dashboards/dashboard-edit-pcr.php');

}
```

i also tried this

```
if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql_pcr)){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = '/cert/forms/dashboards/dashboard-edit-pcr.php';
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

but same result. I don't think the error is from the editing coz when i press <kbd>F5</kbd> it gets updated.

> EDIT: I have notice something. some data gets updated without refresh but still others needs to be refresh manually

Does anyone know why this happens? and how to fix this?.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show more code of what's actually not working...

Comment: what rdbms are you using ? ( MS SQL, MYSQL .. ? )

Comment: @NijrajGelani sorry but i don't know what codes to add here. it updates the data successfully but i have to press F5. if you don't press F5 the contents will not be updated. from what i know, if you will be redirected to a page that page will automatically refresh but in my case it doesn't its just like u have just press the back button.

Comment: @Taki im using MYSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be `cache` problem, try : 
`header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");` 
before redirecting.

Comment: where should i put this? right above header(location) inside the`if `statement?

Comment: yup, between `if` and `header`

Comment: still doesn't work. but i have notice something. some data gets updated but other data need to be manually refresh .

Comment: well .. i'm not sure about this but i think the redirect is faster than the update ( could be a remote DB server or slow server or something ) try `sleep(5)` inside the `if` before the redirect,

Comment: adding `sleep(5)` helps dude. redirect is faster than the update.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not the best way to solve your problem, it's just to identify it, because you're pausing the script for 5 seconds here, so i encourage you to look for something to make sure your data is updated ( query committed ) before the redirect :)

Comment: yeah, ur right. it takes to long to load. but think ill just change its redirect. but do you have any suggestions?

Comment: i think this is exactly what you need :) try oop style : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.multi-query.html , then do your redirect after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal to promptly `exit();` after setting a redirection, unless you have some specific needs otherwise. It may also help to ensure the 'L' in Location is uppercase, and there is a space after the colon.

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

Comment: sorry dude.. still don't work. but appreciate the help.